# Why doesn't pppd over ssh work here? Why can't I kill pppd?

Tags: linux, debian, point-to-point-protocol

I'm trying to setup a [simple ppp tunnel over ssh](http://www.nardol.org/2009/1/12/quick-and-dirty-vpn-with-pppd-and-ssh). It works on several machines just fine. But on one machine, pppd gets "stuck":

```
> pgrep pppd | xargs ps up
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      4178  0.0  0.1   3020  1088 pts/1    Ds+  05:28   0:00 /usr/sbin/pppd
```

Any attempt to kill it (even `sudo kill -9 4178`) has no effect that I can see. `strace -p 4178` also hangs similarly. After it has been started for a while, I start getting messages in `dmesg` like shown below.

It is started like so from another machine:

```
ssh -t root@server /usr/sbin/pppd passive noauth
```

When I do this to one of the machines that work, the remote end's `pppd` spits out garbage/binary data to the console (as expected). When I do it to the one that fails, I get no output from pppd, but the ssh session eventually times out. If I instead ssh to the machine, and then run `/usr/sbin/pppd passive noauth` in a separate step I also get the expected binary output.

I now have a couple of questions:

- What could be up with the one machine where pppd fails? I don't even know where to start looking...
- What could be the difference between `ssh -t root@server /usr/sbin/pppd passive noauth` in a single step and `ssh root@server` and `/usr/sbin/pppd passive noauth` in two steps?
- How can it be that I can't kill the process even with `sudo kill -9`? The only way I know is to reboot.

(I've tried searching for something similar but didn't get anywhere so I'm sorry I don't have any more leads)

Any ideas?

The problem machine runs in debian on VMware "hardware" (as do the ones that work) and it exhibits the problem when cloned and on both debian lenny (original) and squeeze (after upgrade)

`dmesg` entries:

```
[ 1198.727248] INFO: task pppd:4178 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 1198.727507] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1198.727904] pppd            D ece2dc9c     0  4178   4174 0x00000004
[ 1198.727908]  00000098 00000082 f2503520 ece2dc9c 0000b1e7 00000000 c148d1c0 c148d1c0
[ 1198.727913]  f2a06100 f6e071c0 00000000 ece2dc18 f5cd07e0 00000000 ece2d400 ece2dc9d
[ 1198.727918]  00c52300 ece2dcbc f67bfef8 ec98e480 f291cec0 00000000 c10cf5b0 c10dfd21
[ 1198.727923] Call Trace:
[ 1198.727926]  [<c10cf5b0>] ? nameidata_to_filp+0x37/0x41
[ 1198.727929]  [<c10dfd21>] ? dput+0x21/0xb7
[ 1198.727932]  [<c11cfecc>] ? tty_ldisc_ref_wait+0x5f/0x76
[ 1198.727935]  [<c104de7a>] ? wake_up_bit+0x5c/0x5c
[ 1198.727938]  [<c11cb91b>] ? tty_ioctl+0x85f/0x8ba
[ 1198.727941]  [<c10fec18>] ? do_lock_file_wait+0x3d/0xd9
[ 1198.727944]  [<c1162c97>] ? _copy_from_user+0x2b/0x102
[ 1198.727946]  [<c11cb0bc>] ? tty_check_change+0xb9/0xb9
[ 1198.727949]  [<c10dbeb7>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x485/0x4c7
[ 1198.727952]  [<c10db59a>] ? do_fcntl+0x24f/0x3a2
[ 1198.727954]  [<c10dbf3a>] ? sys_ioctl+0x41/0x58
[ 1198.727957]  [<c12c6a1f>] ? sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
[ 1318.457225] INFO: task sshd:4174 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 1318.457500] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1318.457896] sshd            D f25024cc     0  4174   2393 0x00000000
[ 1318.457901]  00000098 00000086 f2a06940 f25024cc 0000b246 00000000 c148d1c0 c148d1c0
[ 1318.457906]  f2503520 f6e071c0 00000000 3f056585 0000000f ece2d4bc 3f056585 f2503520
[ 1318.457911]  ec98bb38 ec98bbdc 00000000 00000000 00000000 c12c09b5 f2503520 c10327cb
[ 1318.457916] Call Trace:
[ 1318.457926]  [<c12c09b5>] ? schedule_hrtimeout_range_clock+0x3c/0xd9
[ 1318.457931]  [<c10327cb>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x13f/0x13f
[ 1318.457935]  [<c11cfecc>] ? tty_ldisc_ref_wait+0x5f/0x76
[ 1318.457940]  [<c104de7a>] ? wake_up_bit+0x5c/0x5c
[ 1318.457943]  [<c11c9ad3>] ? tty_poll+0x32/0x5e
[ 1318.457947]  [<c10dd4d5>] ? do_select+0x2a1/0x42e
[ 1318.457950]  [<c10dcb83>] ? poll_freewait+0x69/0x69
[ 1318.457953]  [<c10dcc25>] ? __pollwait+0xa2/0xa2
[ 1318.457955]  [<c10dcc25>] ? __pollwait+0xa2/0xa2
[ 1318.457958]  [<c10dcc25>] ? __pollwait+0xa2/0xa2
[ 1318.457960]  [<c10dcc25>] ? __pollwait+0xa2/0xa2
[ 1318.457963]  [<c10dcc25>] ? __pollwait+0xa2/0xa2
[ 1318.457965]  [<c10dcc25>] ? __pollwait+0xa2/0xa2
[ 1318.457968]  [<c10dcc25>] ? __pollwait+0xa2/0xa2
[ 1318.457971]  [<c10429c2>] ? lock_timer_base+0x19/0x35
[ 1318.457974]  [<c1042eb5>] ? __mod_timer+0x10c/0x116
[ 1318.457977]  [<c1042f89>] ? mod_timer+0x69/0x6e
[ 1318.457981]  [<c121325d>] ? sk_reset_timer+0xc/0x16
[ 1318.457984]  [<c1252f57>] ? tcp_event_new_data_sent+0x66/0x6b
[ 1318.457987]  [<c1255b85>] ? tcp_write_xmit+0x7a7/0x86a
[ 1318.457990]  [<c121760d>] ? __alloc_skb+0x50/0xfd
[ 1318.457994]  [<c12c12bc>] ? _raw_spin_lock_bh+0x8/0x1e
[ 1318.457996]  [<c1212e98>] ? release_sock+0x10/0xc4
[ 1318.457999]  [<c124b543>] ? tcp_sendmsg+0x6dd/0x7b7
[ 1318.458003]  [<c1162c97>] ? _copy_from_user+0x2b/0x102
[ 1318.458006]  [<c10dd7a0>] ? core_sys_select+0x13e/0x1c3
[ 1318.458009]  [<c12102a3>] ? sock_aio_write+0xc0/0xd4
[ 1318.458012]  [<c10d0655>] ? do_sync_write+0xa0/0xe4
[ 1318.458016]  [<c10b141c>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x222/0x238
[ 1318.458019]  [<c10f6096>] ? fsnotify+0x1de/0x1f9
[ 1318.458022]  [<c10dd9e8>] ? sys_select+0x6e/0x8f
[ 1318.458024]  [<c10d105e>] ? sys_write+0x3c/0x63
[ 1318.458028]  [<c12c6a1f>] ? sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
```

Comment: PPP over SSH. That's a new one.

Comment: @Ingacio: [Nardol: Quick and Dirty VPN with pppd and ssh](http://www.nardol.org/2009/1/12/quick-and-dirty-vpn-with-pppd-and-ssh) - an alternative to an [SSH VPN](http://www.morch.com/2011/11/15/ssh-vpn-with-ip-masquerading-nat/).

Answer (score 0):

I since remembered that that machine is running a new 2.6.39 based custom kernel [I compiled myself](http://groups.google.com/group/sshuttle/browse_thread/thread/6318cb1f4170b2d9/f33dbc3a96bfad83?#f33dbc3a96bfad83). When I reverted to the stock Ubuntu kernel, it worked fine. As far as I remember, I didn't apply any patches to the kernel, I just took a debian unstable `.config` and took it from there.

If anybody else runs into this, I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1366468) with the two kernel configs [working, broken] for future reference. But for now, I'll just stick with the Ubuntu stock kernel for `pppd`.

However, regardless of what config options that are active in the 2.6.39 kernel, a pppd process that can't be killed is still odd...

Comment: you should report the bug with  the stack trace, config and sysinfo included @debian bugracking system, unless someone reported it already in which case u'll just vote for it.